# How to pause a loop after x iterations for x seconds then resume

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

So I have an array that has a list of Channel Names that I would like to join (This is for a Twitch Chat Bot), the API endpoint for joining a channel has a rate limit of 50 joins per 15 seconds. I am trying to figure out the best way to iterate through 50 channel names, pause for 15 seconds, then resume iterating through the rest of the array, pausing for 15 seconds every 50 names.

I had originally tried a generic for loop using a fake, 100 value array, a Modulus Operator, and setTimeout, but to no avail. But in all honesty, I didn't know where to start so it is quite bad.

```
let array = ([...Array(100).keys()].map(x => ++x))

for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (i % 50 === 0) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Waiting 15 seconds.')
        }, 15000);
    } else {
        console.log(array[i])
    }
}
```

Ideally, it would log 1-50, then wait 15 seconds, then log 51-100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `async` and `await` to pause your `for` loop in a fairly simple fashion:

```
// utility function that returns a promise that resolves after t milliseconds
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}

async function processArray(array) {

    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (i % 50 === 0) {
            await delay(15 * 1000);
        } 
        console.log(array[i])
    }
}

let data = ([...Array(100).keys()].map(x => ++x))
processArray(data).then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
});
```

FYI, I don't quite understand why you're trying to use index 1 through 100 on a 100 element array.  I think you should be using indexes 0 through 99 for a 100 element array.  I left the code that way you had in under the assumption that maybe you're doing this on purpose.

Comment: Why the downvote here?  This does exactly what the OP asked for.  I'd be happy to improve the answer with some feedback.

Comment: Works great, exactly what I asked for. Not sure what the down vote was for, but this is exactly what I needed -- never would I have ever thought to do it this way with async and await. Thank you very much. And yeah, there is a specific reason why I am using 1-100 instead of 0-99, it is due to the way I have my database structured, and I appreciate you forming your answer based on what I provided!

Answer (score 1):

```
const _ = require('lodash');
```

Use [iterators/generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) so that you can control when you want the next item instead of fighting to "stop" the execution of the loop.

```
function* myIterator(data) {
  for (const item of data)
    yield item;
}
```

Then set up a function that will do the actual execution, taking the iterator as a parameter. This way, each time you call it, you can pass in the iterator so that it remembers where it left off.

```
function execute(it) {
  // We want to do this in batches of 50
  // (but test with lower value to better see how it works)
  _.range(0, 50).forEach(() => {
    // Get next item
    const item = it.next();

    // If no more items, we're done
    if (item.done) return;

    else {
      // Do something with the item
      console.log(item.value);
    };
  });

  // Pause for 15 seconds and then continue execution
  setTimeout(() => execute(it), 15000);
}
```

Create your data, generate an iterator from it and then execute.

```
(function main() {
  const data = _.range(1, 101);
  const it = myIterator(data);

  execute(it);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create the loop manually. Here's a simplified example...

```
var array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
var i = 0;
function loop(){
   if(i>=array.length) return;
   if(i==3){
      setTimeout(function(){
          i++;
          loop();          
      },15000);
      return;  
   }
   i++;
   console.log(array[i]);
   loop();
}
loop();
```

Comment: This wouldn't repeat after the 15 seconds has passed.

Comment: Ok fixed it, just incremented the i before calling the function again

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 let array = ([...Array(100).keys()].map(x => ++x))

const startLoop = currentIndex => {
  for (let i = currentIndex; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (i % 50 === 0) {
        setTimeout(() => {
           console.log('Waiting 15 seconds.');
           startLoop(i + 1);
        }, 15000)
        break;
    } 
     console.log(array[i])
  }
}

startLoop(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing a recursive loop function from scratch (at the cost of performance) is probably the simplest solution, but you can accomplish this iteratively using a `while` loop and a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), without compromising performance.

In the code below, every time the 1-based index of the loop reaches a multiple of `batch_size`, an `await` is called which stops execution until the Promise resolves. The promise is just a `setTimeout` call, which waits for `pause_ms` before allowing the loop to continue. The values are slightly different here just to make testing easier; you can change them freely to meet your needs.

```js
const vals = [...new Array(20)].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1);
console.log(vals);

async function iterateBatches(arr, batch_size, pause_ms) {
  // Create a promise generator that will automatically resolve after the desired number of millseconds.
  const wait = () => new Promise(r => {
    setTimeout(r, pause_ms)
  });
  
  // Establish the starting and ending points for the iteration.
  const len = arr.length;
  let i = 0;

  // As long as the loop hasn't reached the final element,
  while (i < len) {
    // Perform an operation with the value in your array.
    console.log(i, vals[i]);
    // If we've reached the end of the array, break out of the loop to prevent an unneeded iteration.
    if (i >= len - 1) break;
    // Increment the index (this is also equal to the 1-based index, which saves us some lines).
    // If the 1-based index is a multiple of batch_size and we're not on the first iteration, wait for our promise generator.
    if (++i % batch_size === 0 && i > 0) await wait();
  }
  console.log("Done!");
}

iterateBatches(vals, 5, 2000);
```